# JAR que no se ejecuta

Tags: java-8

Hola amigos/as duda de torpe desarrollador. Actualizo mi pregunta para que sea útil. El archivo se abre desde consola usando la instrucción `java -jar .\servidorchat.jar`, pero no con dobleclick. es un chat de consola, sin GUI.

He probado otros proyectos con GUI, y tampoco se me ejecutan. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué errores te muestra?

Comment: Que mensaje de error sale al hacer doble click?

Comment: `La ruta especificada no existe`

Comment: he cambiado la ruta y la variabla home-java a JDK. y ahora, vuelve a no reaccionar. El mensaje anterior, fue al colocar el JRE. Tenia entendido que era indiferente usar uno u otro para ejecutar un .JAR

Comment: `java -jar ./servidorchat.jar` Creo que te esta escapando la `s` por poner diagonal invertida solo ponlo así: `java -jar servidorchat.jar`. Ningún jar se va abrir con doble click a menos que tenga Interfaz Grafica de Usuario (GUI) con awt, swing, javaFX, etc. ¿Tu jar tiene GUI o solo haces procesamiento de consola?

Comment: ¿Cuál sistema operativo usas? Si es Windows, podríasconvertir ese JAR a un EXE. http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/   Si tu necesidad solo dar un click para abrirlo.

Comment: Una buena idea lo de converitr el JAR a EXE.  lo probaré.  respecto a si mi JAR tiene GUI, no la tiene. Solo hace procesamiento de consola.
Gracias por la ayuda. De momento, no he solucionado nada. Estoy a punto de desinstalar todo, JRE y JDK, para empezar de cero.

Comment: @Fernando Carraro, con la conversión funciona. Ahora solo tengo que descubrir porque los archivos de audio no los reconoce, en la iDE si, pero eso ya es otra pregunta. Me hubiera gustado resolver el misterio de porque no puedo ejecutar ningún JAR, ya que los JAR que tienen GUI , he hecho pruebas, tampoco se ejecutan. Gracias a todos.

Comment: si no tienes GUI debes correrlo desde consola sí o sí, si quieres que el usuario pueda correrlo con doble click te recomiendo poner un bat con tu comando para correrlo desde consola ya que el bat se puede abrir con doble click.